# How to get a "params object[]" value from WebApi call?

Tags: routes, asp.net-web-api2

I want to give an undetermined number of parameters on a rest api call like:
http://localhost/api/SomeController/a/b/c/d

but I can't get it working. I'm getting only "keys" array with only one element with value "a/b/c/d"

Here is my Api method:

```
// GET: api/Base/5
    //[Route("{prms}")]
    [ResponseType(typeof(IHttpActionResult))]
    public virtual IHttpActionResult Get([FromUri]params object[] keys)
    {
        IHttpActionResult result = null;
        try
        {
            //var arrayKeys = keys.Split('/');
            using (var ctx = new MegaContext())
            {
                TEntity entidad = Repository<TEntity>.Find(context: ctx, prms: keys);

                if (entidad == null)
                {
                    result = NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    result = Ok(entidad.Map());
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            result = InternalServerError(Helpers.ExceptionHelper.ProccessException(ex));
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Try `http://localhost/api/SomeController?keys[0]=a&keys[1]=b&keys[2]=c&keys[3]=d` or `http://localhost/api/SomeController?[0]=a&[1]=b&[2]=c&[3]=d`

Comment: That should work but I don't want to increase the request with unnecessary data repeating "keys" for each parameter in the array.
There is no way to do something with this request format: 

http://localhost/api/SomeController/a/b/c/d ?